# OpenShift fails at TASK [template_service_broker : Verify that TSB is running]

Tags: openshift

Installing OpenShift with Ansible playbook. The installation fails at template_service_broker : Verify that TSB is running. after 60 tries.

```
fatal: [icp4dos1]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 60, "changed": false, "content": "",     "failed": true, "msg": "Status code was not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error   [Errno 113] No route to host>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url":   "https://apiserver.openshift-template-service-broker.svc/healthz"} 

[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd
glusterfs
# define openshift variables
[OSEv3:vars]
openshift_deployment_type=openshift-enterprise
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_storage_glusterfs_storageclass=true
os_firewall_use_firewalld=True


###
[masters]
dos1 openshift_ip=10.170.164.37
[glusterfs]
dos1worker-00 glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/xvde" ]'
dos1worker-01 glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/xvde" ]'
dos1worker-02 glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/xvde" ]'
[etcd]
dos1 openshift_ip=10.170.164.37
[nodes]
dos1 openshift_ip=10.170.164.37
dos1worker-00 openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
dos1worker-01 openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
dos1worker-02 openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
dos1master-00
dos1master-01
dos1master-02
```

- ansible-playbook v2.4.5.0
- oc v3.9.31
- kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5

  [root@icp4dos1 ~]# curl https://apiserver.openshift-template-service- broker.svc/healthz
  curl: (7) Failed connect to apiserver.openshift-template-service-      broker.svc:443; No route to host
  [root@icp4dos1 ~]# curl -v https://apiserver.openshift-template-service-broker.svc/healthz

  - About to connect() to apiserver.openshift-template-service-broker.svc port 443 (#0)
  - Trying 172.30.99.63...
  - No route to host
  - Failed connect to apiserver.openshift-template-service-broker.svc:443; No    route to host
  - Closing connection 0
    curl: (7) Failed connect to apiserver.openshift-template-service-broker.svc:443;    No route to host

Answer (score 0):

It seems the internal service name is not resolved in your `OCP` cluster.
I suggest the diagnose steps as follows.
Usually, `v3.9` search the `DNS name` using the `dnsmasq` in the `node` and if `DNS` name is the internal service name, the it processes in the `OCP cluster`.
But in your case, it seems the internal service name is searched in the external `DNS` server from your `OCP`.

- You can check whether or not other internal service name is resolved as follows.

> curl -kvs https://kubernetes.default.svc/healthz ok

- The result of above checking is same error with your issues, then your cluster can not resolve the internal service name due to wrong `dnsmasq` configuration.
- Check your DNS related configuration files as follows.

  - `cat /etc/resolve.conf` and then the resolve is similar with the following one ?

> search cluster.local [sub domain your node host]
>     nameserver [your
>   node host ip address]

- The result of `cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/*` would be included the following config.

> server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1 
>   server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1

Refer [DNS for OCP](https://blog.openshift.com/dns-changes-red-hat-openshift-container-platform-3-6/) for more details.

Your configuration is not matched above examples, then you can modify it.

I hope it help you :^)